# Matplotlib in Python parallel plotting

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I've got a def in Python that is setting all Label values and also plots the values. The problem is that matplotlib is extremely slow so I wanna ask you guys if you know a way to plot the values parallel to the Label-updates.

I know that matplotlib isn't thread-safe so putting it into another thread hasn't helped me (it didn't plot anything).

Also, I am not that familiar with multiprocessing so I'd be happy for suggestions apart from that.

```
def UebergabeTkinter():
    ZeitAnfang = time.time()
    fig = Figure(figsize = (3, 3))
    axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
    axis.legend()
    axis.grid()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=10,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=2)

    global LUX_Meter0 
    global Pyranometer0 
    global PAR_Sensor0 
    global LUX_Meter1 
    global Pyranometer1 
    global PAR_Sensor1 
    global LUX_Meter2 
    global Pyranometer2 
    global PAR_Sensor2 
    global LUX_Meter3 
    global Pyranometer3 
    global PAR_Sensor3 

    while 1:

        LaengeArray = next(MinutenWertYield)

        Mittelwert0 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Maximum0 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Minimum0 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Standardabweichung0 = next(MinutenWertYield)

        Mittelwert1 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Maximum1 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Minimum1 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Standardabweichung1 = next(MinutenWertYield)

        Mittelwert2 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Maximum2 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Minimum2 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Standardabweichung2 = next(MinutenWertYield)

        Mittelwert3 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Maximum3 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Minimum3 = next(MinutenWertYield)
        Standardabweichung3 = next(MinutenWertYield)

        CompleteValue, DatumVar = UebergabeWert()
        Variable1.set(round(CompleteValue[0]*LUX_Meter0*Pyranometer0*PAR_Sensor0))
        Variable2.set(round(CompleteValue[1]*LUX_Meter1*Pyranometer1*PAR_Sensor1))
        Variable3.set(round(CompleteValue[2]*LUX_Meter2*Pyranometer2*PAR_Sensor2))
        Variable4.set(round(CompleteValue[3]*LUX_Meter3*Pyranometer3*PAR_Sensor3))

        VariableMittelwert0.set(round(Mittelwert0))
        VariableMaximum0.set(Maximum0)
        VariableMinimum0.set(Minimum0)
        VariableStandardabweichung0.set(Standardabweichung0)

        VariableMittelwert1.set(round(Mittelwert1))
        VariableMaximum1.set(Maximum1)
        VariableMinimum1.set(Minimum1)
        VariableStandardabweichung1.set(Standardabweichung1)

        VariableMittelwert2.set(round(Mittelwert2))
        VariableMaximum2.set(Maximum2)
        VariableMinimum2.set(Minimum2)
        VariableStandardabweichung2.set(Standardabweichung2)

        VariableMittelwert3.set(round(Mittelwert3))
        VariableMaximum3.set(Maximum3)
        VariableMinimum3.set(Minimum3)
        VariableStandardabweichung3.set(Standardabweichung3)

        ZeitEnde = time.time()

        if ZeitEnde-ZeitAnfang >= 15:
            LinienBreite = next(GrafikYield)
            ArrayGrafik = next(GrafikYield)
            DatumArray = next(GrafikYield)

            fig.clear()
            axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
            axis.plot(LinienBreite,ArrayGrafik,'b-')
            axis.set_xticks(LinienBreite)
            axis.set_xticklabels(DatumArray)
            canvas.draw()


            ZeitAnfang = time.time()

        root.update()
```

Comment: Python multithreading is a difficult beast to wrangle due to the GIL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock. Long story short, you won't get any parallelism unless your threads are IO bound. There might be other ways to speed this up, though

Comment: Also, you'll have better luck if you submit code that actually runs (for example, give us the imports you're using, define `MinutenWertYield`, etc).

Comment: You're *sure* it's the plotting that's taking a long time, though? Have you profiled your code? If you submit a runable example I can probably help you speed it up a little.

Comment: Don't clear your figure each time, just update the plot's xdata and ydata: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html